# Two level nested c++ class works with GCC but fails with Clang

Tags: c++, macos, clang, nested-class

I'm having problems defining an inner class outside of the class in which it is declared.

```
struct Base {
    struct A {
        struct B;
    };
    struct A::B {
    };
};
```

It compiles and works with GCC but fails on Clang with this error:

```
innerclass.cpp:6:12: error: non-friend class member 'B' cannot have a qualified name
    struct A::B {
           ~~~^
```

If the outermost class Base is omitted the code works on Clang.

Is it illegal to define an inner class this way? If so, how should it be done?

Platform:
OS X 10.8.3
XCode 4.6.2
Clang Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
GCC gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid GCC is being to permissive. Paragraph 9/1 of the C++11 Standard specifies that a *class-head-name* is a:

*nested-name-specifier(opt) class-name*

Which means a qualified name can be used as the name of a class. Also, the first part of paragraph 9/11 specifies:

> **If a *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier*, the *class-specifier* shall refer to a class that was
>   previously declared directly in the class or namespace to which the *nested-name-specifier* refers**, [...]

And you did indeed declare class `B` inside class `A`. However, the second part of the same paragraph adds:

> [...] and the *class-specifier* **shall appear in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration**. In such cases, the *nested-name-specifier* of the *class-head-name* of the definition shall not begin with a
>   *decltype-specifier*.

In your case, the *class-specifier* `struct A::B { }` does *not* appear in the scope of namespace, but in the scope of a class (try changing `struct Base` into `namespace Base` and you will see that Clang accepts it).

Therefore, the correct way of fixing this is to define the class at namespace scope, and not inside `Base`:

```
// ...

struct Base::A::B
{
};
```